Chrome extension: Approach to persist prepended query parameter across the same domain?
I have extension which prepends certain query parameters to a URL after toggling an input box. But, it drops off when navigating to another page on the same domain.
My goal – I want to persist the query parameter ?active=true across the same domain. For example:
www.example.com?active=true
www.example.com/product/main?active=true
www.example.com/help?active=true

Heres what I have so far:
popup.html – Heres the Input I interact with to run JS script that adds the query parameter:
<input type="checkbox" name="query" id="queryParams">

popup.js – Heres the script that prepends query parameter
const queryParamaOptions = document.querySelector('#queryParams');

function toggleQueryParams(e) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        if (e.target.checked === false) {
            chrome.storage.local.set({
                query: false
            });
            return;
        } else {
            chrome.storage.local.set({
                query: true
            });

            // Heres where parameter is created
            const params = encodeURI('active=true');
            const url = tabs[0].url;
            const hashStart = url.indexOf('#') === -1 ? url.length : url.indexOf('#');
            const querySymbol = url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
            var newUrl = `${url.substring(
                0,
                hashStart
            )}${querySymbol}${params}${url.substring(hashStart)}`;

            // Refresh page with new URL
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { url: newUrl });
        }
    });
}

queryParamaOptions.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleQueryParams(e));

Current thoughts

I am thinking to store the domain in localstorage when I first run toggleQueryParams
Use something like chrome.tabs.onUpdated to watch for url changes on changeInfo.url within the background script because the pop.up is closed at this point whilst navigating different pages
Use an if condition to check if the stored domain matches the current domain. If so then run toggleQueryParams

Any thoughts?

If you do that, make sure to change the toggleQueryParams function to check if the parameter already exist before trying to add it, or do that in the chrome.tabs.onUpdated callback so you don't end up with an infinite loop.

Dude! This is what I did in background script and unfortunately I did run into an infite loop and gave up on Saturday evening. Now I am reviewing with a clear mind and implemented your suggestion! It works and I'm so grateful for your feedback @Titus

To watch for URL changes, try using location.href in MutationObserver:
var lastURL = location.href;
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    if (lastURL !== location.href) {
        // your code to append to URL here
    }
});
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });


"The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree." MDN Web Docs


The href property of the Location interface is a stringifier that returns a string containing the whole URL, and allows the href to be updated. MDN Web Docs

